# iPhone Development on Hackintosh

Tags: iphone

My question is in regards to developing code for the iPhone / iTouch.

What with Apple's transition to the Intel platform for their chip, it is obviously now possible to run their OS on a PC.

So, with that, and my inherently cheap nature, I was wondering if it was possible to bypass the purchase of a refurbished Mac by running the iPhone SDK on a Hackintosh?

As I am more of a hobbyist then a serious developer at present, I'd basically like to get my feet wet before fully committing to this endeavor.  In the long term I know that it would be better to purchase a Mac...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible. I developed my first app on a Dell running the iATKOS OSX patch.

Whether it's worth it or not really comes down to how difficult it is to get a hackintosh install (Kalyway / iATKOS) running on your PC. With some PCs it's trivial and everything works. For others it's a nightmare and your networking/audio/graphics will never work completely. If you need to run a patched kernel (e.g. you don't have an Intel Core 2 Duo chipset) things become really awkward.

Your best bet is to take a note of the hardware in your PC and do some research on the various OSX86 forums.

Assuming you get everything working the only future concern is software updates. iPhone SDKs generally require the very latest OSX update (e.g. 10.5.6), but installing updates on hackintoshes with patched kernels is a nightmare.

If you enjoy tinkering with this type of thing and are comfortable partitioning your HDD and playing with boot flags then I'd say go for it. If not, consider picking up a used Mac-Mini on eBay/craigslist or something. If you find out that iPhone development really isn't for you then you can resell it lose practically nothing.

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2016 :)

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2017 :)

Comment: @KamalSingh but what if Apple decides to lock its hardware by matters of signing etc, so that you must buy a mac book in 2018?

Comment: Mark my words @Marco Alka 

"That will never happen."

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2018 :)

Comment: Hey guys how to get xcode on iATKOS, or get most recent patch?

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2019 :)

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2020. :-)

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2021. :)

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2022 :-)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can, but save yourself some time and pain.

Pick up a Mac mini or an iMac.

Comment: Looks like at least 4 people like to waste time and experience pain. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's possible. But you are restricted to the choice of hardware for the hackintosh. Even if you get it right, no one can guarantee everything will work (sound, lan, etc.). If you can run the OS, you can run xcode with the SDK. But I don't think you'll be 100% satisfied with the end result.

As I see it if you want to run os x it's better to invest in a mac mini than in hardware for a hackintosh. Asuming you'll be buying all the components for the hackintosh.

Answer (score 5):

I was in this dilemma recently, and decided to go with a real Mac rather than a Hackintosh after hearing the stories of my friend (who is doing it specifically for iPhone development).  He was able to get iPhone development working, but his hackintosh is always having one issue or another; the most recent one was a constant boot cycling, wherein the machine would immediately reboot after loading the OS.

Look on the bright side: Apple products are popular and easy to sell.  If you get one and sell it before the next generation comes out you can get most of your money back - money that would have been spent anyways on a new hard drive (to quarantine your hackintosh, heh) or OSX (assuming you meant to get the software in at least a remotely legal fashion).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. I have. But is it worth it?

If you are doing it for fun it's worth it.

If you are doing it for a real, useable Mac it's not worth it.

Now you will have a billion guys come down on me for saying that because some guys have built some truly impressive rigs but they are missing the point of a Mac. Macs just work well and are a pleasure to use while PC's just get stuff done and you probably secretly hate it.

I did it just for fun but I ended up spending more on a Hackintosh than I would have if I just bought a Mac Mini.  Of course my computer is 4x as fast but it's just not the same as a real Mac.  On Mac's everything just works... it's really nice.  But on my Hackintosh nothing works without direct intervention on my part... not very nice.

I always planned on using that computer for windows development anyway so it wasn't a waste but otherwise it would have been a HUGE waste.

Comment: That's in absolutely no way a testament to Macs being better. If you run Windows on a "Mac", it just works. Everything works. You try running OSX on anything except hardware which Apple have specifically chosen and said "you WILL use this configuration" and you have to jump through all sorts of ridiculous hoops.

Comment: That is to say... it's funny you suggest that everything on a Mac "just works". Better to say it "just works on this configuration", whereas Windows really just "works".

Comment: "Macs just work well and are a pleasure to use while PC's just get stuff done and you probably secretly hate it." - well said.. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it. I have 3 hackintoshes that we develop on, but at the end of the day you will need a real mac to be an apple developer.

Comment: thats means we cannot send apps to App store using a hackintosh?

Comment: I do it all the time.

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see with the Hackintosh approach is that if you get it working now, you are not guaranteed to have the same machine working when an update to Mac OS comes out in the future, and this could be especially important if the iPhone SDK and/or developer tools that you want to use are hosted only on the next generation of the system software.

In the long run, I think it'll be better to go with a cheap (and even a used) Mac of some kind, like a mini or a MacBook.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, I started learning iPhone/Objective-C/Cocoa development using a virtual machine and an image of OSX (it was a pain to setup though and I think I could only use OSX 10.5.2)

It's just not worth the hassle, in the end I just stumped up £365 or so for a second-hand 2007 model MacBook off eBay and it's been smooth sailing ever since.

Answer (score 2):

On a $10 P4 2.4GHz, 1GB RAM, hackintosh works fine and xcode/iphone sdk works as well.  Its a little slow, but stable, and a very viable option for someone looking to just test the water of iphone development, without committing the cash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you. right now I am learning iphone app development in a Hackintosh (iATKOS S3 version2).

See http://wiki.osx86project.org/ and http://insanelymac.com/ for any problem with installing     hackintosh

Answer (score 2):

Hackintoshes are a great value. You can spend anywhere from $400 to $4000 and get an extremely capable machine.

You want to go with a Gigabyte brand Z87 motherboard, Intel Core i CPUs, Nvidia graphics, and SSDs. Avoid budget hardware, it usually isn't compatible. Or you could go the Intel NUC route and get a NUC, a small PCIe SSD (32GB or 64GB should do the trick), and some laptop ram.

Do your research and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Visual Studio (2019) and Xamarin Forms will enable to develop IPhone apps by utilizing Xamarin Hot-Restart (Preview) feature without requiring a Mac.

In my case, I have an IPhone and would like to develop an IPhone app however I was being forced (until this day) to buy a Mac (or at least chosing the Hackintosh way) develop an IPhone App. Now I can write and debug my app directly on my IPhone (which is fair!).

Details here: 
https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.5 year i use my hackintosh for daily coding, and it's working perfectly fine.

but because i have hardware and software knowledge i suggest you to go with mac-min, or if you want to create hackintosh here are some tips.

never directly buy any device like motherboards or graphic-cards, instead check for hackintosh support this cheapest or not.

never install latest version of macOS in hackintosh, (missing driver issues)

if you want to test in real device, you have not update your real device like iPhone or iPad. The new iPhone will not connect to the old system OS.

Better understand disk partitions and software for hackintosh like clover    etc.

- you save money

- reInstall Os to update
- drive fail issue
- take much time than expect.
- 

Answer (score -1):

If you have so little belief in yourself that you feel the need to save a couple of hundred dollars by hacking a pseudo-Mac together just don't bother trying in the first place.

Furthermore you will pretty certainly fail (or spend so much time trying to succeed you'll have wasted vastly more time getting things to work than you saved on cost).  The two clinchers are

1. You **have** to run code on a iPhone or touch, because the emulator is **not** perfect and will mislead you without you even being aware of it - I have code that runs on the emulator but not as expected on hardware
2. Apple's key signing is hard enough to get working with the real thing, it took me a couple of hours and I'm not alone - there's a great many posts out there on development forums from people having difficulties managing it.  Getting it working on a Hacked machine - well you may be lucky, but are you prepared to gamble?

Comment: Neither of these are "clinchers". You can debug on a physical iPhone with a hackintosh, and the certificate stuff in Xcode is no worse than it is on an actual Mac.

Comment: -1: "you will pretty certainly fail". What? Justify this. As long as you have the right hardware, OSX86 is perfectly possible. Point 1: He sounds like he already has an iPhone. Point 2: It will be just the same on a Hackintosh.