# Exporting my android app to iphone?

Tags: java, android, iphone, c

Ive made an app on Android and I want to be able to sell the app for iphone and android. I dont want to have to learn objective C. Is there any possible way I can do this?

Comment: If your app is written in Java, no.  If its written in C or C++ you'll still have to rewrite the UI parts and system interaction in Objective C, but you can reuse your business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options but none of them are very nice. I know of no direct converter.

To reuse the majority of your code checkout RoboVM

http://www.robovm.com/

It is used by libgdx to allow for using Java to do cross platform development.

Pretty much all your other options as far as I have seen would involve using a proprietary language or recreating your app as HTML5.

In the end you will have to write some iOS code. At least now/soon you can use Swift instead of Objective-C =)

Comment: So by essentially just running my code through robovm I can export it to an ios version? Or are there other things I have to do in robovm to get an iphone app

Comment: You will have to rewrite petty much every part of your app that interacts with the phone, display, controls, input, etc. But you can keep around all your logic. If your app is well abstracted it won't be too costly to do this.

Comment: So roboVM is specified for iphones? I cant do this in say Eclipse or titanium?

Comment: You can use Eclipse no problem. Eclipse is just an IDE. See the docs to get started http://www.robovm.com/docs

Comment: Okay, it says I must have a mac computer, I dont have one.

Comment: Yes ultimately if you want to develop for iphone you will need mac software to at the least sign your builds. You can install OS X on a PC. See this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644225/iphone-development-on-hackintosh