# Does one need an XCode to develop iOS apps using C++ on Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, visual-studio, mobile-development

I've googled and not able to find a good answer. I do not have a Mac at the moment and have to develop an app using C++. Do I need any stuff additional to Visual Studio?

I mean I'm planning to use Xamarin and do I need an Xcode or at least Mac without Xcode?

Please check the link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147405.aspx

Comment: tl;dr - you MUST have a Mac to develop for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDEs required to develop iOS Applications ([Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/), [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)) are only available for `Mac OS`. So you would need to install a [hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/) version of `Mac OS` on your PC and start developing Apps and when you are ready with your App, you can buy a Mac and legitimately submit to the App-Store.

Please refer to this link for more information: [iPhone Development on Hackintosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644225/iphone-development-on-hackintosh)

Comment: Thank you @enigma. I've chosen getting a Mac and developed the app using Xcode. Also I was able to use C++ with Objective-C.