# How to build iOS app using Flutter with Windows 10

Tags: ios, windows, flutter

How can I build iOS app using Flutter with Windows 10?

I clicked in (build - Flutter - iOS app) from the tab bar, but it responds:

> Building for iOS is only supported on the Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible... You have to have a Mac to build an app for iOS.. That is Apple rules!!

Comment: can I use Linux?? or also that not possible??

Comment: No.. Only Mac.. To build or even simulate an iOS app you need to install Xcode which is available only for Mac

Comment: Is there a way to build with IPhone?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible on a Windows 10. This way Apple can force developers to buy Apple hardware to develop for both platforms. You can try Hackintosh on a PC which will let you create IOS apps on non apple hardware.

Comment: can I use Linux?? or also that not possible??

Comment: @MohmmedMalas No, you need a Mac

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly with Windows. You can achieve it though by using external services that provide Mac build machines. One of these services is [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI).

Once you have Odevio installed and set up you can start a publication build.

This will pre-publish your app on Apple Connect. You then have to add your screenshots etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have xcode to create IOS app which is available only on OSX. Not on Windows. Not on Linux or anything. But using Hackintosh (Mac OS on normal desktop or laptop hardware) you can build IOS app on that PC or laptop though.

Comment: I'm not sure about building and app for iOS is hackintosh an answer but I'm pretty sure the Hackintosh is not a solution to add an app into apple store...

Comment: Using Hackintosh, you can publish to app store also. The only problem is you need to jump through different hoops and isn't simple. But it can be done.

Comment: You can also see: http://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/2015/06/04/develop-apps-on-windows-pc/

Comment: So I guess it is but with a lot of trouble.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644225/iphone-development-on-hackintosh

Answer (score 0):

Apple only allows iOS emulator which is running on macOS, so we need to run macOS on your non-mac computer

Two ways:

1. Hackintosh (macOS running on non-mac device)
2. Virtual Machine (VM)

The first way can give you a high-performance environment (compare to VM) to run iOS simulator. But it's strict to your hardware. The best way is to use hardware as close to the original mac as possible.

The second way has better compatibility. You just need to download macOS's image and install system in VMware or other VM software.

But VM will degrade performance, and in my case neither of my graphics cards seem to work, so I'm guessing my CPU was rendering the GUI. Also, modern macOS (meaning better visuals but more rendering pressure) is slower than old macOS.