# Is there a way to run flutter from vs code to a real device like iphone 11 pro? Working on windows

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, emulation

So i'm new at flutter and i want to run my app to my real device. Working on windows 10 with vs code. I want to do this because when i run my app with android emulators my pc starts going slow.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build iOS app using Flutter with Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171411/how-to-build-ios-app-using-flutter-with-windows-10)

Comment: https://ravynos.com/

Comment: You can not do that with iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial if you want to run your application on an actual device with `USB` connection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aohkII1C4JY&ab_channel=JohannesMilke

And also there is another way to run your app on an actual device which you can do it `wirelessly`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BymD9pxtVwY&t=161s&ab_channel=AppMakingAcademy